# Search a word in particular column in SQL Server using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL Server query for `Events` which are in categories 5 or 6, but which don't mention either `War` or `Death` in the `EventDetails` column.

My query:

```
select 
    EventName, EventDetails
from 
    tblEvent
where 
    CategoryID in (5, 6)
    and (EventDetails not like '% War %'
         or EventDetails not like '% Death %')
```

But this returns output with word 'War':

[image]

My questions:

1. Why didn't 'War II' get filtered?
2. Do I need to specify (in the query) all the possibilities for the word 'War' to be appeared in EventDetails column like '% War', '%War', 'War %', etc?
3. Is there any other option to filter for particular word in particular column?

I still have a confusion that, we might not know whether in which place the word 'War' would come, whether in the middle or in the start or at the end. so do we need to add condition for each of this possibility, like

```
select EventName, EventDetails
from tblEvent
where  
CategoryID in (5,6)
AND EventDetails not like '% War %'
    AND EventDetails not like '% War'
    AND EventDetails not like 'War %'
    AND EventDetails not like '%War%'
    AND EventDetails not like '% Death %'
    AND EventDetails not like '% Death'
    AND EventDetails not like 'Death %'
    AND EventDetails not like '%Death%'
```

Is this correct query standard?

Comment: change the `or` to `and`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
select EventName,
    EventDetails
from tblEvent
where CategoryID in (5, 6)
    and EventDetails not like '% War %'
    and EventDetails not like '% Death %'
```

Also note that the above will allow `war` or `WAR` etc. To do a case insensitive search, you can use lower (or upper) :

```
select EventName,
    EventDetails
from tblEvent
where CategoryID in (5, 6)
    and lower(EventDetails) not like '% war %'
    and lower(EventDetails) not like '% death %'
```

Also think about the situation where war is last word in the sentence.

For e.g.:

```
This is a war. abcd. . .
```

Again this will not match either. To work with this, you may have to use pattern based matching.